# My page won't load despite routes on Flask pointing to the right .html code

Tags: html, flask, web-applications

I have been bashing my head for a while here...

I am trying to make my index open a page (lessonplan.html) after hitting a button.

`This is the captions route on my deployed website:

```
@app.route('/captions', methods=['GET']) def captions(): global transcript_text, lesson  # Declare transcript_text as a global variable youtube_link = request.args.get('youtube_link')
if youtube_link:
    transcript_list = get_youtube_transcript(youtube_link)
    transcript_text = ' '.join([item['text'] for item in transcript_list])

    try:
        openai.api_key = os.getenv("sk-xxx")
        lesson_title, lesson = generate_lesson(transcript_text)
    except Exception as e:
        lesson_title = "Lesson Title Generation Error"
        lesson = f"Error generating lesson: {str(e)}"

    qr_code_filename = generate_qr_code(youtube_link)
    return render_template('lessonplan.html', youtube_link=youtube_link, lesson_title=lesson_title, lesson=lesson, qr_code=qr_code_filename)
```

Now, this is my index:

```
Guide Maker body { font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; background-color: #f4f4f4; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh; }
    .container {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        text-align: center;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #333;
    }

    form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    label {
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #555;
    }

    input, select {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    button {
        background-color: #007bff;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    button:hover {
        background-color: #0056b3;
    }
</style>
Welcome to the Guide Maker
Enter YouTube Link: Get Captions

<!-- Include your JavaScript files -->
<script src="/static/script_lesson.js"></script>
<script src="/static/script_chatbox.js"></script>
```

And my lessonpage.html whch should open up as I hit the button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lesson Generated</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="content-to-print">
        <h2>{{ lesson_title }}</h2>
        <h3>Watch the video here:</h3>
        <img src="{{ url_for('qrcode', filename=qr_code) }}" alt="QR Code">

        <div class="lesson-content">
            <div class="formatted-lesson">{{ lesson | safe }}</div>
        </div>

        <!-- Hidden input to store the captions URL -->
        <input type="hidden" id="captions-url" value="{{ url_for('captions') }}">

        <!-- JavaScript function and rest of your HTML content -->
        <div id="boxA">
            <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Ask a question...">
            <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
        </div>
        <div id="boxB"></div>

        <script>
            function sendMessage() {
                // Your JavaScript code for sendMessage
            }

            // Rest of your JavaScript code...
        </script>

        <a class="download-button" href="{{ url_for('download_pdf', youtube_link=youtube_link, lesson_title=lesson_title, lesson=lesson) }}">Download PDF</a>

        <a href="/">Go Back</a>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script_chatbox.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script_lesson.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of opening up, I just get:

[http://website.xyz/%7B%7B%20url_for('captions')%20%7D%7D](http://website.xyz/%7B%7B%20url_for(%27captions%27)%20%7D%7D) 404 (Not Found).

My folder structure is correct. When I deploy this locally, I have no problem whatsoever.

Comment: "Deploy locally" is somewhat confusing terminology. Consider "run locally" since "deploy" implies production. In any case, if it works locally but fails in production, then consider providing details about the environment where it's deployed, since it seems that's where the problem is likely to be.